# How to publish a codename one app on Apple Store without using the "codename one iOS certificate Wizard?

Tags: codenameone

I created my Apple ID and activated the two-factor authentication as apple documentation said I should do.

When I try to execute the "Codename-One-iOS certificates-wizard", I always got an error related to the two-factor authentication.

After some research, I read on Codename One documentation that the wizard doesn't work with the two-factor authentication.

Then, I tried to turn off the two-factor authentication, But I couldn't do that. The Apple company doesn't allow to revert this configuration. I tried several approaches ( via iCloud and Xcode applications, via web sites Apple ID, And Apple Developer Program, .... No one of them offered options to do that.

Then, I think my only option is to do things using the traditional approach. without the help of the Wizard.

How can I do that?
I didn't find any help about how to publish a Codename One application on Apple Store using the normal path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that Codename One Settings is up to date and make sure that only one device is associated with your account. The certificate wizard should work with two factor authentication but has an issue with more than one device.

You can follow the instructions on the developer guide to generate a certificate manually: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/signing.html